How do I read UE4 localization files with CUE4Parse?
I am trying to read the localization files (.locres and .locmeta) from an unencrypted UE4 PAK file using CUE4Parse. But when I try to call LoadObject or LoadObjectAll to read the file I get errors saying it can't find the .uasset

Looking at the code in LoadLocalization shows how to approach this, by creating an archiver reader from the 'File' and then instantiating the relevant object from the reader. I used the following code to extract all LOC files that match a directory pattern.
var cacheDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TMP");
cacheDir = cacheDir.Replace("\\", "/");

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console(theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate).CreateLogger();

var gameDir = {Directory where PAK files Live};
var provider = new DefaultFileProvider(gameDir, SearchOption.AllDirectories, false, new VersionContainer(EGame.GAME_UE4_27));

// Scan local files and read them to know what it has to deal with (PAK/UTOC/UCAS/UASSET/UMAP)
provider.Initialize();

// Decrypt basic info (1 guid - 1 key)
provider.SubmitKey(new FGuid(), new FAesKey(AES key for game or all 0s if not encrypted)); 

provider.LoadLocalization(ELanguage.English);

foreach(var key in provider.Files.Keys)
{
    if(key.Contains({partial path for LOC files}))
    {
        var outPath = cacheDir+$"/LOC/{game}" + key[(key.IndexOf(_locFilesDir)+_locFilesDir.Length-1)..(key.LastIndexOf('/')+1)];
        new FileInfo(outPath).Directory.Create();
        var file = provider.Files[key];
        file.TryCreateReader(out var archive);

        if(key.EndsWith(".locres"))
        {
            var locres = new FTextLocalizationResource(archive);
            var locJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(locres, Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText(outPath + "Game.json", locJson);
        }
        else if(key.EndsWith(".locmeta"))
        {
            var locmeta = new FTextLocalizationMetaDataResource(archive);
            var locJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(locmeta, Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText(outPath + "Game.json", locJson);
        }
    }
}

